# N, N-Discrete fourier transform

Tags: image-processing, matlab, discrete-signals, fourier-transform

What is $N$,N-point Discrete fourier transform? Is it different from 2D Fourier transform?

and how to compute $N$, N-point Discrete Fourier Transform of a given laplacian filter kernel? say for a given filter `{{0, 2, 0}, {1, -2, 1}, {0, 2, 0}}`, where $N = 103$ and frequency and spatial indices ranges from -100 to 100, without using `fft2` and `ifft2` functions.

Comment: The word sounds like, yes, a square 2D DFT. But: to be certain, we'd need to know the context in which this arose.

Comment: Please provide a quote or reference where found this term

Comment: More conventionally a two-dimensional (2D) discrete-Fourier transform $X[k_1,k_2]$ is labelled like: $N \times M$-point 2D-DFT, where $N$ refers to first dimension and $M$ to the second.

Comment: Voting to close this as lacking detail since no clarification regarding context was given, sadly :(